# Grunt: How do recursive templates work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, lodash

I'm new to Grunt, and I'm having some issues with recursive templates. Here's a concrete, minimal example:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Stash path here so we can reference it from templates.
    path: path,
    argPrint: function(arg1, arg2) { return "arg1: " + arg1 + " arg2: " + arg2; },
    build: {
      root_dir: __dirname,
      build_dir: '<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>',
      vendor_dir: '<%= path.resolve(build.build_dir, "vendor") %>',
      classes_dir: '<%= path.resolve(build.vendor_dir, "classes") %>',
      test: '<%= argPrint(build.build_dir, "vendor")  %>'
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('print_build_dir', 'Prints the build directory.', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("build.root_dir"));
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("build.build_dir"));
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("build.vendor_dir"));
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("build.classes_dir"));
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("build.test"));
  });
};
```

Pop that into a `Gruntfile.js`, run `npm install grunt`, and then run `grunt print_build_dir`.

If you are in `/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test`, I would *expect* that the output would be:

```
$ grunt print_build_dir
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor/classes
arg1: /Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev arg2: vendor
```

Instead, the output is:

```
$ grunt print_build_dir
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor
/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor/classes
arg1: /Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev arg2: vendor
```

What's going on here? From the `test` configuration property, it's apparent that `path.resolve` should receive the correct arguments for the `vendor_dir` property -- namely, it would resolve to `path.resolve("/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev", "vendor")` -- but I am completely confused about why it is prepending the value of `build.root_dir` with an extra forward slash to the property.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated by both me and my struggling `Gruntfile`. Thanks!

EDIT: As a pre-emptive addendum, I realize I do not need to use templates to realize this particular example -- I could use `path.resolve` directly. However, in my non-example `Gruntfile`, one of the directory names in `path.resolve` is a dynamically-set property, necessitating the use of templates.

EDIT2: As Andrew points out, template expansions works on `vendor_dir` in the following way:

```
'<%= path.resolve(build.build_dir, "vendor") %>' ->
  path.resolve('<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>', "vendor") ->
    '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>/vendor' ->
      '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/vendor'
```

My `test` property worked, as it expanded like so:

```
'<%= argPrint(build.build_dir, "vendor")  %>' ->
  argPrint('<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>', "vendor") ->
    'arg1: <%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %> arg2: vendor' ->
       'arg1: /Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test arg2: vendor'
```

I don't understand why they made this design decision, but I can easily emulate the template semantics I want by wrapping all of these in a function that repeatedly processes the string until all `<%=` are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me start with a working sample.

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    path: path,
    argPrint: function(arg1, arg2) { return "arg1: " + arg1 + " arg2: " + arg2; },
    resolvePath: function(from, to) { return path.resolve(grunt.config.process(from), to); },
    build: {
      root_dir: __dirname,
      build_dir: "<%= resolvePath(build.root_dir, 'dev')%>",
      vendor_dir: "<%= resolvePath(build.build_dir, 'vendor') %>",
      classes_dir: "<%= resolvePath(build.vendor_dir, 'classes') %>",
      test: "<%= argPrint(build.build_dir, 'vendor')  %>"
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('print_build_dir', 'Prints the build directory.', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config.get("build.root_dir")); 
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config.get("build.build_dir")); 
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config.get("build.vendor_dir"));  
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config.get("build.classes_dir"));
    grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config.get("build.test"));
  });
};
```

This outputs what you expect :

> /Users/andrewtremblay/Development/grunt-test
>
> /Users/andrewtremblay/Development/grunt-test/dev
>
> /Users/andrewtremblay/Development/grunt-test/dev/vendor
>
> /Users/andrewtremblay/Development/grunt-test/dev/vendor/classes
>
> arg1: /Users/andrewtremblay/Development/grunt-test/dev arg2: vendor

What I noticed when testing this out with my `ResolvePath` function was the values being passed to `from` weren't being processed. (instead of using the output of `config.get('build.build_dir')` it was using the result of `config.getRaw('build.build_dir')`)

I have no idea if this is a bug or not, but I think the answer lies with `path.resolve` and how passing it processable variables leads to undefined behavior.

[From the docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) (with my emphasis):

> `path.resolve([from ...], to)`
>
> If `to` isn't already absolute `from` arguments are prepended in right to
>   left order, until an absolute path is found. **If after using all from
>   paths still no absolute path is found, the current working directory
>   is used as well.** The resulting path is normalized, and trailing
>   slashes are removed unless the path gets resolved to the root
>   directory.

That (plus the fact that `path.resolve` was not processing your config objects) could explain why your working directory kept getting prepended.

Comment: This is it. I added a debug print of arg1 to argPrint, and noticed that it was being called with the raw template. My mental model of templating was incorrect; I thought it replaced all config variables immediately, but it instead processes the template one level, evals it, and then processes any further templates recursively until finished.

Answer (score 0):

When Grunt does a `get` from the `config` it processes the values if it finds the template pattern.

It looks like it processes the templates until it finds a string without a template pattern. So each step in your situation looks like:

```
__dirname =>
  '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test'

build.build_dir =>
  '<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %> =>
    __dirname + "dev" =>
      '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev'

build.vendor_dir =>
  '<%= path.resolve(build.build_dir, "vendor") %>' =>
    '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>/vendor' =>
      '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor'

build.classes_dir =>
  '<%= path.resolve(build.vendor_dir, "classes") %>' =>
    '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/<%= path.resolve(build.build_dir, "vendor") %>'/classes' =>
      '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/<%= path.resolve(build.root_dir, "dev") %>/vendor/classes' =>
        '/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test//Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev/vendor/classes'
```

I don't know if there's a good way around this except to expand your configs manually at run-time:

```
grunt.config("build.build_dir", grunt.config("build.build_dir"))
grunt.config("build.vendor_dir", grunt.config("build.vendor_dir"))
grunt.config("build.classes_dir", grunt.config("build.classes_dir"))
```

Comment: This template expansion doesn't make sense... `vendor_dir` and `test` are identical -- *except* they call different functions!

This form of expansion would yield the following for `test`:

    `/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/arg1: /Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/dev arg2: vendor`

Furthermore, where is the extraneous forward slash coming from? `root_dir` is `/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test`, not `/Users/jvilk/Code/grunt-test/`... is Grunt doing weird basename extraction because it looks like a file path...?

Thank you for responding, though.

Comment: I didn't notice the difference in argPrint. I think @Andrew's answer explains it.